# Sum over a power set of probability weights

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have a set $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$. 
Let us a define 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}(S)=\{ A:   A \subset S, A \neq S, A \neq \emptyset  \}.
\end{align}
That is $\mathcal{B}(S)$ is a almost a power set and it doesn't contain $S$.

Suppose we are given as sequence $\{p_A \}_{A \in \mathcal{B}(S)}$ such that   $p_A \in [0,1]$   and

\begin{align}
\sum_{A \in  \mathcal{B}(S):  j \in A} p_A=1 , \forall j \in S. 
\end{align}

> What are some good upper bounds on  \begin{align} \sum_{A \in 
> \mathcal{B}(S)} p_A . \end{align}

Please also help me come up with a better title for this post.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you don't use $S$ for both the original set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ *and* the index of the sum, for a start.

Comment: Also, as a remark:  if you write $$\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{S\in \mathcal{B}([n]) : j\in S} p_S = n$$ and rewrite it, swapping the sums, you get $$\sum_{S\in \mathcal{B}([n])} \lvert S\rvert p_S = n\,.$$

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, very good point.  I changed it to $A$. Also, can your remark be used to come up with an upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is a sample space with $n$ discrete outcomes.   $p_{\cdot}$ is a probability measure over that space, with all the usual properties including additivity over disjoint unions.

$$\forall A\subseteq S~:~p_A = \sum_{s\in A}p_{\{s\}}$$

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of $S$ which contain $k$ elements. Of these $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ will contain any particular element, $s$.  So:
$${{\sum_{A\in\mathcal B(S)} p(A) }~{= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mathop{\sum\qquad}\limits_{A\in\mathcal B(S): \lvert A\rvert =k} p_A \\= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{s\in S}\binom{n-1}{k-1}p_{\{s\}}}}$$

Simplify via the identity $\sum_{k=0}^r \binom r k = 2^r$

Comment: So you saying that $\sum_{A \in \mathcal{B}(S)} p(A)= 2^{n-1}  \sum_{s \in S}  p_s$. Is that correct?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Is it obvious that $p(S)=1$?